# Recursive N-Level MySQL Query

Tags: mysql, sql, hierarchical-data, recursive-query

I'm trying to build url's from Word Press Post/Pages.  I'm able to connect to the database and retrieve the data I need.  However some pages have parents, which are just other pages, for example:

```
|id|post_name|post_parent|post_status|url
|1 |post_1   |0          |publish    |post_1
|2 |post_2   |3          |publish    |post_3/post2
|3 |post_3   |0          |draft      |post_3
```

What I want to be able to do is build the url column using a MySQL query.  At the moment I'm using some c# code to do it, however this should be possible using SQL?  The version of MySQL is 14.14 Distrib 5.1.73.  I don't have any control over the version of MySQL.

Comment: Unfortunately, MySQL doesn't support recursive queries until version 8.0, so if you can't upgrade, your options are pretty limited. I show an example of a recursive query and a workaround in my answer to https://stackoverflow.com/a/192462/20860 but the workaround requires storing all paths through the tree in a separate table.

Comment: You can also search past answers with the 'mysql' and 'hierarchical-data' tags: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mysql+hierarchical-data

Comment: @BillKarwin, many thanks for your reply and the link - at the moment I'm using joins to go 4 levels deep.  It's horrible, but it does whats required at the moment.  Hopefully I'll have some time over the holidays to refactor!